# Drupal doesn't invoke a hook function until I don't clean the cache

Tags: 7, caching

I created a module, and implemented `hook_form_alter()` using the following code.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'mymodule_form_id') {
    $form['#validate'] = array('mymodule_form_validate');
  }
}
```

Drupal can call the function correctly, and run well for several days.

But one day Drupal did not call the function anymore, until I cleared the cache. Why?

Comment: Have you disabled/enabled the module ?

Comment: Not sure what's going on but I can say you to be cautious because you are removing all existing validation handlers of the module and set it only to mymodule_form_validate.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why clearing the caches fixed the issue is because all hooks are cached in Drupal 7 via [module_implements()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_implements/7). My guess is something odd happened to your cache and thus your hook went missing from the cache.